# How does conversion of string to char pointer work in C++

Tags: c++

I need some help understanding how to convert `string` to a `char *pointer`.

string text;

```
char *str = &text[0];
```

Could someone please kindly explain to me how does the conversion of text to char in the above case work?

Comment: Use the `.c_str()` member function. And make your `str` variable `const`.

Comment: there is no conversion taking place, `text[0]` is a `char` and with `&` you get a pointer to it

Comment: `text[0]` is a `char` being the first character of the string. `&text[0]` is a pointer to that `char`. So it is a `char*`. It is probably worth reading a good book to get the fundamentals https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *text* is a *string* then *text[0]* is not just a *char* but a `char&` to the specified char (a reference to the char), so `&text[0]` is a `char*`

But warning, the internal `char*` of a string may not be null terminated, this is why `c_str()` exists and forces the null terminating char to be present, and also returns a *const* pointer because of course this is more secure

Comment: In modern C++ internal buffer is required to be null-terminated at all times.